# Which perfect tense for habitual action?

Tags: present-perfect, habitual-aspect

If an action started at some point in the past and still hasn't been completed, we are supposed to use the present perfect progressive, for example "I've been watching TV for two hours."

Which tense should I use if I want to say that I only watch TV on the weekend and have done it for five years?

If the answer is the present perfect progressive "I've been watching TV on the weekend for 5 years," wouldnt it be a contradiction to the rule that says progressive tenses are used for actions that are in progress, not for habits?

Answer (score -1):

It is not a contradiction - it represents a continuing and unfinished habit.

Comment: Hmmm, a continuing habit... it's like Noah Chomsky's colorless green ideas :D but I actually like your answer; it explains it well. Thank you :)

Comment: Perhaps I should have written ".. it represents a continuing series of (regular, frequent, habitual) actions that were unfinished at the time referred to."

Comment: I think it's very good the way it is ;)